# How to get get Case Email Thread in Visual Flow?

Tags: case, visual-workflow, email2case

I'm trying to send email notifications when someone enters a Case Comment. Since there doesn't appear to be a way to do this via configuration, I have create a Visual Flow that will create a Case Comment Notification record, which will in turn send an email. That works just fine.

However, I need to include the Case Email Thread so that when the requester replies to the notification, it is tracked back to the case. But, when I try to find this field on the Case object in Visual Flow, it doesn't appear.

How can I obtain the Email Thread in Visual Flow so that I can include it in my email?

Answer (score 0):

While I realize this is not ideal or even recommended, one can use this formula from Salesforce ...

```
"ref:_" & LEFT($Organization.Id,5) & SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT($Organization.Id,11), "0", "" )& "._" & LEFT(Id,5) & SUBSTITUTE(Left(RIGHT(Id,10), 5), "0", "") & RIGHT(Id,5) & ":ref"
```

... or this if the first formula doesn't work:

```
"ref:_" & LEFT($Organization.Id,5) & SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT($Organization.Id,10), "0", "" )& "._" & LEFT(Id,5) & SUBSTITUTE(Left(RIGHT(Id,10), 5), "0", "") & RIGHT(Id,5) & ":ref"
```

Source: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006trk

I used it and it worked fine, but there's no guarantee it will continue to work in the future.